# How to replace consecutive characters from directory names, recursively

Tags: bash, find, sed, awk, perl

What is the best way to replace all **consecutive characters** such as `_+-."'?` from a directory and all sub directory's names using GNU `bash`, version 4.3, using tools `awk`, `sed`, Perl `rename` or `find`?

AS suggested by @Ralf to rephrase:

**The example would be to rename directories from**

**inital_situation**
`.
├── dir1---FooFoo---xFoo.FOO
│   └── file1---FooFoo---xFoo.FOO.mp4
├── dir2+++FooFOO___xFoo.FOO
│   └── file2___FooFOO___xFoo.FOO.mp4
├── dir3...FooFOO...xFoo...FOO
│   └── file3...FooFOO...xFoo...FOO.mp4
├── dir4._-FOO._-xFoo._-FOO
│   └── file4._-FOO._-xFoo._-FOO.mp4
├── dir5+++FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_xFoo
│   └── file5_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_xFoo.mp4
├── file1---FooFoo---xFoo.FOO.mp4
├── file2+++FooFOO___xFoo.FOO.mp4
├── file3...FooFOO...xFoo...FOO.mp4
├── file4._-FOO._-xFoo._-FOO.mp4
├── file5+++FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_FOO_-_xFoo.mp4
├── xFoo_-[xFoo]_-[dir6]
│   └── xFoo_-[xFoo]-file6.mp4
└── xFoo_-[xFoo]-file6.mp4`

**to**

**expected_results**
`.
├── dir1-FooFoo-xFoo-FOO
│   └── file1-FooFoo-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── dir2-FooFOO-xFoo-FOO
│   └── file2-FooFOO-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── dir3-FooFOO-xFoo-FOO
│   └── file3-FooFOO-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── dir4-FOO-xFoo-FOO
│   └── file4-FOO-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── dir5-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-xFoo
│   └── file5-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-xFoo.mp4
├── file1-FooFoo-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── file2-FooFOO-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── file3-FooFOO-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── file4-FOO-xFoo-FOO.mp4
├── file5-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-FOO-xFoo.mp4
├── xFoo-xFoo-dir6
│   └── xFoo-xFoo-file6.mp4
└── xFoo-xFoo-file6.mp4`

The following 2 examples from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/how-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names-using-a-bash-script) works well for renaming directories, sub directories and files.

```
find -name "* *" -type d | rename 's/ /_/g'    # do the directories first
find -name "* *" -type f | rename 's/ /_/g'
```

[This is able to handle multiple layers of files and directories in a single bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709619/3818865)

```
find . -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/_/-/g' "{}" \;
```

I have attempted several versions to replace or remove certain characters.

Replace dots and replace underscores

```
for f in *; do fn=`echo $f | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\([^.]*\)$/\1\n\2/;s/\./-/g;s/\n/./g'`; mv $f $fn; done
```

The following will remove brackets and parenthesis

```
rename 's/\[//g' * ; rename 's/\]//g' *
rename 's/\(//g' * ; rename 's/\)//g' *
```

Comment: What should happen to `foo-.-?bar?++-baz."`?

Comment: `foo-.-?bar?++-baz."`  should become `foo-bar-baz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial situation:

```sh
$ find .
.
./foo---foo...foo
./foo---foo...foo/foo...foo...foo
./foo---foo...foo/foo...foo...foo/file..name...name.extension
./foo---foo...foo/foo-+-+-+-+-+X
./foo---foo...foo/foo-+-+-+-+-+X/07. Testing.mov
./foo---foo...foo/foo------------foo
./foo---foo...foo/foo------------foo/01. Introduction.mov
```

Now execute:

```sh
$ find . -depth -execdir rename -E 's%^./%%' -E "s/[-_\.+\"'\?]{2,}/-/g" {} \;
./07. Testing.mov not renamed: 07. Testing.mov already exists
./01. Introduction.mov not renamed: 01. Introduction.mov already exists
./. not renamed: . already exists
```

Result:

```sh
$ find .
.
./foo-foo-foo
./foo-foo-foo/foo-foo-foo
./foo-foo-foo/foo-foo-foo/file-name-name.extension
./foo-foo-foo/foo-foo
./foo-foo-foo/foo-foo/01. Introduction.mov
./foo-foo-foo/foo-X
./foo-foo-foo/foo-X/07. Testing.mov
```

---

Your question should really contain examples like I added with "Initial situation:" and "Result:". Only that way anyone is able to understand what you want. Without it, it is just guessing game.

Comment: I attempted `find . -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename -n "s/[-_+\.'\"\?]+/-/g" {} \;`  my results  without renaming leaving the `-n`. **/01. Introduction.mov renamed as -/01- Introduction-mov**  this renames the file extension to a hypen

Comment: And it also changes the leading `./` to `-/`. Not good. Do you really want to replace the `.` (dot) with a hyphen (as  in the question)?

Comment: I am only attempting to change consecutive characters such as `_+-."'?` from a directory. The dot for the file extension should remain. If the folder name contains a special characters such as `_+-."'?` that should be replaced with the hypen

Comment: @OffGrid you keep emphasizing "consecutive characters" yet your example appears to show `FOO.foo` changing a single character to become `FOO-foo`. Also what exactly do you mean by "the dot for the file extension" in the context of a directory name?

Comment: This following string I would remove the consecutive dots and hyphens. Top level parent `foo---foo...foo` Sub directory / `foo...foo...foo` /  `file..name...name.extension`

Comment: @OffGrid See update

Comment: @Ralf I believe you have a clear understanding of the scenario. I was about to use `tree` to show the directory's and files, thank you for the clear directory tree including the file structure with an understanding of what I am attempting to explain... NICE problem/solution WORK!!